# Javascript is not compiling in route in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have two controllers, that two things was loading dynamically, but in one of my controller having the script, but when I'm loading the controller(userEntryContriller) that script was not compiling below script.

Controller1.html:

```
<div ng-controller="userEntryContriller">
    <div id="appletbox" class="photobox">
        <script>
            console.log("hello");
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller2.html:

```
<div ng-controller="stationRegController">
    <div id="appletbox" class="photobox">
        <p>Hello Hai</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="punchApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/station/register"></i> Station Registration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/user/userEntry"></i> User Entry</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>   
    </div> 
</body>
```

Script:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('punchApp', ['ngRoute']);
phonecatApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.
  when('/station/register', {
    templateUrl: 'resources/views/Controller2.html',
    controller: 'stationRegController'
  }).
  when('/user/userEntry', {
    templateUrl: 'resources/views/Controller1.html',
    controller: 'userEntryContriller'
  }).
  otherwise({ redirectTo: '/station/register' });
});

phonecatApp.controller('userEntryContriller', ['$scope', '$http',
 function($scope, $http) {
}]);

phonecatApp.controller('stationRegController', ['$scope', '$http',
 function($scope, $http) {
}]);
```

**Edit:**

`console.log("hello");` is not displaying in controller1.html.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your code ever get to the `console.log("hello")` statement?

Comment: could you share in fiddle ?

Comment: @SyntaxRules No it is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Call me captain obvious - but it doesn't appear you are referencing your script anywhere.

If you are doing this on your local machine, be sure to include your script tags :) (angularjs, your script, etc...).

If this is in JSFiddle then this answer is totally wrong. Paste your JSFiddle and I'll update this answer.